# docker-compose v3 share the same volume mount locations between multiple containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Previously I used `volumes_from` to mount multiple volume locations to multiple containers, like so:

```
app:
  image: mageinferno/magento2-nginx:1.11-1
  links:
    - phpfpm
  volumes_from:
    - appdata
  ports:
    - 8000:80

phpfpm:
  image: mageinferno/magento2-php:7.0-fpm-1
  links:
    - db
  volumes_from:
    - appdata

appdata:
  image: tianon/true
  volumes:
    - /var/www/html
    - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer
    - ./html/app/code:/var/www/html/app/code
    - ./html/app/design:/var/www/html/app/design
```

However, in docker-compose version 3 when using native volume mounts, `volumes_from` is not available, which leads me to do something like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: mageinferno/magento2-nginx:1.11-1
    links:
      - phpfpm
    volumes:
      - appdata:/var/www/html
      - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer
      - ./html/app/code:/var/www/html/app/code
      - ./html/app/design:/var/www/html/app/design
    ports:
      - 8000:80

  phpfpm:
    image: mageinferno/magento2-php:7.0-fpm-1
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - appdata:/var/www/html
      - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer
      - ./html/app/code:/var/www/html/app/code
      - ./html/app/design:/var/www/html/app/design
```

Is there any way I can reference the same group of volume mounts to multiple services, without defining them twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML supports "anchors" for re-using bits: (From https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/)

```
# YAML also has a handy feature called 'anchors', which let you easily duplicate
# content across your document. Both of these keys will have the same value:
anchored_content: &anchor_name This string will appear as the value of two keys.
other_anchor: *anchor_name

# Anchors can be used to duplicate/inherit properties
base: &base
    name: Everyone has same name

foo: &foo
    <<: *base
    age: 10

bar: &bar
    <<: *base
    age: 20
```

Comment: Awesomeness. I did have to change a couple things around as I want to pass in an array. Going with a format like this:

`version: "3" 

services:
  app:
    volumes: &appvolumes
      - appdata:/var/www/html
      - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer
      - ./html/app/code:/var/www/html/app/code
      - ./html/app/design:/var/www/html/app/design 

  phpfpm:
    volumes: *appvolumes`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a docker-compose version 3 example where an anchor is used for the **environment** variables.

The values are set the first time they are used, and then referenced in any additional services that use the same environment variables.

Note the use of *&environment* in setting the anchor, and **environment* in referencing it.

```
version: '3'
services:
  ui:
    build:
      context: ./ui
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - cluster-net
    environment: &environment
      A_VAR: 'first-var'
      ANOTHER_VAR: 'second-var'
  api:
    build:
      context: ./api
    networks:
      - cluster-net
    environment: *environment

networks:
  cluster-net:
    driver: bridge
```